# Do I need to add the line 'mov ebp, esp' in NASM assembly function if it still works without it?

Tags: assembly, stack, nasm, stack-pointer

In one of my class examples, a function that takes in int parameter *integer* begins like:

```
recursive_sum:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp     ;set EBP=ESP
    pusha                ;save all registers(probably overkill)
    mov     ebx, [ebp+8] ;ebx=integer(parameter #1)
```

But in a different class example, a function that takes in int parameter *num* begins like:

```
f:
    enter 8,0    ;num in [ebp+8] ,local var x, sum in [ebp-4],[ebp-8]
    push  ebx
    push  ecx
    push  edx
    mov   eax, [ebp+8]    ;eax=num
```

In what case would one need the `mov ebp, esp` instruction? Please explain in terms of C, java, or through an example. And I am not looking for a basic definition of the ESP register

Comment: You'll need to post whole functions. We can't tell if that's important in the part of them that you cut off.

Comment: C compilers set up a stack frame for you; this is not explainable in terms of C.  You have to understand what a frame pointer is, and that `enter` sets one up the same way that `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp` does.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/enter

Comment: @PeterCordes Now it all makes more sense to me! I understood how the stack works, it turns out I just had the wrong idea about the `enter` instruction. Thank you!